# Trying to install module win32clipboard

Tags: python, python-2.7, installation, raw-input

I'm new to python and i'm trying to install win32clipboard to be able to use this code:

```
import win32clipboard
win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
win32clipboard.SetClipboardText('testing 123')
win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()

# get clipboard data
win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
data = win32clipboard.GetClipboardData()
win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()
print data
raw_input()
```

How do i exactly install the necessary module to be able to do so?
I'm using python version 2.72.

Comment: What did you already try?

Answer (score 15):

This module is part of [pywin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/) module.

To install:

1. Go to http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/
2. Choose the latest build, e.g.: http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build%20219/
3. Download the installer for your system, e.g.: `pywin32-219.win-amd64-py2.7.exe`
4. Run the installer.
5. Use the Python you've installed it for to run your `win32clipboard` script.

Comment: Dude i know that, what i don't know how to do is install it, i want to be able to use that code. That link you gave me has not helped a single bit, they are just a bunch of files many of which i don't need. I need a step by step how to install it. Running windows 7 x86.

Comment: [Direct link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build%20218/pywin32-218.win32-py2.7.exe/download) to the file you need. Just install it and code above will work.

Comment: Latest releases are now here: https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/releases

Answer (score 14):

For those still here 7 years later

run this in your shell or cmd (assuming you added python to PATH, otherwise do that first)

```
pip install pywin32
```