# how to install win32clipboard

Tags: python, windows, python-3.7

I'm trying to install `win32clipboard` but for some reason says :

> No module named win32clipboard

and when tried `pip install win32clipboard`
I get :

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement win32clipboard (from versions: )
>   No matching distribution found for win32clipboard

I've python 3.7, and installed pypiwin32 through pip, still not working.

Any idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trying to install module win32clipboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15310121/trying-to-install-module-win32clipboard)

Comment: it is a part of pywin32

Comment: @TilmanB.akaNerdyyy THANK YOU. All I did is to install pywin32 through pychram. works just fine.

Answer (score 20):

`win32clipboard` is part of a package called `pywin32`. You can install pywin32 by doing the following:

`pip install pywin32`

then you should be able to import win32clipboard:

```
import win32clipboard
```

at least this worked for me :D

Comment: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32 (from versions: )

Comment: Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pywin32

[notice] A new release of pip available: 22.1.2 -> 22.2
[notice] To update, run: python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.